Getting the error, while creating the topic in Kafka server? ERROR Exiting JVM with code 1
I'm encountering the following error: ERROR Exiting JVM with code 1 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils) when attempting to create a topic on a Kafka server running on Ubuntu. This issue occurs only on the Ubuntu server, while topic creation works fine on a Linux server.
On Ubuntu, I have installed JDK using the command sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre and have set the appropriate environment variables. However, on the Linux server, where I used sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk, topic creation proceeds successfully.
Getting ERROR Exiting JVM with code 1....When I tried to create the topic in kafka-server.
I used the below command to create topic...
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic zootest --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

Could anyone provide suggestions or insights on resolving this discrepancy between the two environments? Thanks.

Ubuntu is "a Linux server". What exact command are you running? You shouldn't be using Zookeeper to create topics. What version of Kafka are you using? And you should install Java 17 for latest kafka

Zookeeper was embedded in kafka.... Once I started the zookeeper and Kafka servers, I used the below command to create topic...
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic zootest --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
The error was occured only when am using ubuntu-20, but worked in Linux-2..
Kafka version = kafka_2.12-3.5.2.tgz

Zookeeper is not "embedded", there is a separate zookeeper-server-start command. But also, using Zookeeper at all is deprecated as of Kafka 3.7. Have you tried upgrading? Or using Docker? https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart Or just using AWS MSK rather than running Kafka on your own EC2?
